# RavenDB(v 4.0): sorting doesn't work properly for nullable values

Tags: sorting, ravendb, nullable

Result: 111, null, Aaa, Bbb

Expected result: 111, Aaa, Bbb, null

Is it possible to put all null-values to the end of the list that RavenDB index returns?